# X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: make

I am trying to install tcl and tk on my linux server.I don't have the root password,So I am installing them in my home directory.I am using below method for installing it manually.

```
cd ~/tcl8.5.11/unix
./configure --prefix=/home/cnel711 --exec-prefix=/home/cnel711
make
make install

cd ~/tk8.5.11/unix
./configure --prefix=/home/cnel711 --exec-prefix=/home/cnel711 --with-tcl=/home/cnel711/tcl8.5.11/unix
make
make install
```

I was able to install tcl without any problem ,but I am facing problem while installing tk.
`configure` for `tk` worked fine ,I am facing problem while using `make`.I am getting this error.

```
X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
```

I found out this file was missing on the server.So,I downloaded `libX11-devel` from [here](http://ftp.eq.uc.pt/software/pc/prog/cygwin/release/X.Org/libX11/libX11-devel/).Again,I installed it in my home directory.Then I exported the path to the header files and when I use `which` command to find Xlib.h,it locates ths file.

```
>which Xlib.h
~/include/X11/Xlib.h
```

Now, when I try to install `tk` again `configure` works fine as usual but I get the same error again while using `make` `X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory`.

Please help me out,what possibly is going wrong here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is looking in standard locations for the header file: it doesn't know that you've put it in your home directory.

Try this, which sets a compiler option to point to the right place:

```
cd ~/tcl8.5.11/unix
CFLAGS="-I$HOME/include" ./configure --prefix=/home/cnel711 --exec-prefix=/home/cnel711
make
make install
```

Answer (score 4):

More or less the same answer as Flup ;)

```
export CFLAGS="-I$HOME/include"
make
```

If you end up needing to link libraries in your home directory:

```
export CFLAGS="-I$HOME/include -L$HOME/lib"
```

However, if you do that you'll also need:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib
```

when you run the executable you're making.